# How to concatenate values using associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I am using foreach loop and I want to display related value in separate array my current result is this:

```
{"response": {
    "message":"",
    "statistics": [
    {
        "player_name": "J. Bruun Larsen",
        "goals_total": "2"
    },
    {
        "player_name": "Ö. Toprak",
        "goals_total": "1"
    },

    {
        "player_name": "M. Hitz",
        "goals_assists": "0"
    },
    {
        "player_name": "M. Hitz",
        "goals_assists": "0"
    },

    {
        "player_name": "Ö. Toprak",
        "cards_yellow": "6"
    },
    {
        "player_name": "Ö. Toprak",
        "cards_yellow": "5"
    },

    {
        "player_name": "Ö. Toprak",
        "cards_red": "0"
    },
    {
        "player_name": "Ö. Toprak",
        "cards_red": "0"
    },
  ]}
}
```

I want to display each related value in its own array.
example: the goals_total value in goals_total array and like this the goals_assist value in goal_assist array.
I am using foreach loop in php.

Comment: This data is an object?

Comment: this data come from database but all the data shown in one array i want a separate array for all the related data

Comment: Could you please do `var_dump($data);` and inform about data structure (it's necessary to know this). I've made a demo for an object and array of objects. Need to be sure in some stuff.

Comment: thanks alot brother i solve my problem but my array show 0 index i want to show the array name according to data forexample if the data contain the goals i want the array name to be goal

Comment: foreach ($search_goals as   $goals)
            {
                 $goals_array[]  = $goals;
             }//end foreach             and my output is                                                                  
       [
        {
            "player_name": "J. Bruun Larsen",
            "goals_total": "2"
        },
       
  ]             and i want my array name to be Goal

Comment: This [demo](https://3v4l.org/DC2C9) works with objects. That's why I'm asking you to give me data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You might use PHP core function called  [`array_colum()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) which can direct return values of keys which exists in array.

```
    {
        "player_name": "M. Hitz",
        "goals_assists": "0"
    },
    {
        "player_name": "M. Hitz",
        "goals_assists": "0"
    },

    {
        "player_name": ". Toprak",
        "cards_yellow": "6"
    },
    {
        "player_name": ". Toprak",
        "cards_yellow": "5"
    },

    {
        "player_name": ". Toprak",
        "cards_red": "0"
    },
    {
        "player_name": ". Toprak",
        "cards_red": "0"
    }
  ]}
}',1);
$goals_total  = array_column($data['response']['statistics'],'goals_total');
$goals_assist  = array_column($data['response']['statistics'],'goals_assist');
```